# Need clearer instructions on using .admx group policy templates

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2008 domain controller running group policy for our domain.  Recently we started adding some Windows Server 2012 servers to the domain and some of the group policy settings do not match between the DC and the 2012 servers, mainly Terminal Services being renamed to Remote Desktop Connections.

I downloaded the following templates:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36991

These are supposed to give me the Server 2012 options in group policy in order to update those servers via group policy on my DC.

I also read through the instructions here on using .admx templates:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748955%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

I'm lost though.  The instructions say to create a central store and move files from one location to another.  After downloading and running the .msi installer for these templates at the download location though the templates do not show in either of the locations listed on my DC.  I'm confused on how to access these settings within group policy.  I know the installer installed the templates because if I run it again it asks me to repair or remove the templates but I don't see them in group policy and I don't see any files for this template or even with today's timestamp under the sysvol locations listed in the instructions.

Comment: Well, you're probably confused about what you're trying to do... understandable, since the instructions are pretty obtuse and non-intuitive.  Please update your question and let me know - are you trying to set this up so that a bunch of admins can use these templates (central store approach) or do you just need to use them yourself on your workstation (basically a local "installation" approach)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was actually pretty simple.  I just couldn't find where my templates were installed, for some weird reason despite the instructions from Microsoft clearly stating where these need to be installed the .msi installs them under Program Files by default.  By removing them and reinstalling the .msi package I saw that was the install location and changed it to the correct one.  Once in the central store Group Policy was able to see these settings and I was able to edit them.